# Finding the indices of a value in a distance matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, bioinformatics

From a list of 461 X, Y, and Z coordinates, I created a distance matrix with SciPy that looks like this

```
[[ 0.          3.78112691  6.55159315 ... 63.40661118 62.2923149
  64.71125443]
 [ 3.78112691  0.          3.76986434 ... 60.79913069 59.55251531
  61.87364432]
 [ 6.55159315  3.76986434  0.         ... 61.12392086 59.65959803
  61.94572052]
 ...
 [63.40661118 60.79913069 61.12392086 ...  0.          3.8003808
   5.63044026]
 [62.2923149  59.55251531 59.65959803 ...  3.8003808   0.
   3.82889361]
 [64.71125443 61.87364432 61.94572052 ...  5.63044026  3.82889361
   0.        ]]
```

I also wrote code to allow the user to extract values from the distance matrix that are less than or equal to a certain value and then write it to a text file

```
radius = int(input("Enter the radius threshold for contact (Angstrom): "))


###########This code will extract every pair <= radius##################
f = open('contact.txt', 'w')

for i in distance_matrix:
    for j in i:
        if j <= radius:
            if j != 0:
                f.write(str(j) + '\n')

print("File contact.txt written")
#########################################################################
```

And the text file (contact.txt) is simply a long list of values <= to the user-specified value. Is there a way to also write what pair of indices these values come from? For example, if value "a" is found at the intersection of index b on the x axis and value c on the y axis, is there a way to add that to the output text file?

Comment: Check out `np.where`.

Comment: considering you are scanning the matrix with for loops you could jsut use enumerate()

Answer (score 0):

As per comment you can use enumerate which is kind of equivalent to

```
zip( range( len(vec)), vec)
```

to do this:

```
f = open('contact.txt', 'w')

for n1, i in enumerate(distance_matrix):
    for n2 ,j in enumerate(i):
        if j <= radius:
            if j != 0:
                f.write(str(j) + '\n')

print("File contact.txt written")
```

where n1 and n2 are your indices

Answer (score 0):

You can use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
indices = np.where((distance_matrix <= radius) & (distance_matrix != 0))
row_col_vals = list(zip(*indices, distance_matrix[indices]))  # gives you a list or (row, col, value) tuples
```

Example, if `radius = 5` and

```
distance_matrix =  np.array([[2, 6], [0, 3]])
```

then

```
row_col_vals = [(0, 0, 2), (1, 1, 3)]
```

To write to file:

```
f = open('contact.txt', 'w')
for row, col, val in row_col_vals:
    print(row, col, val, file=f)
f.close()
```

HTH.